# How to get a good fragrance from burnt rosemary?

Tags: herbs, cocktails

There's a particular cocktail I'm trying to produce which has a garnish of burnt fresh rosemary. Properly done, the rosemary is burnt with a torch to release some very fragrant, herbal smoke.

However when trying to do this at home, I get smoke that smells like...just smoke. Very little rosemary fragrance.

What's the trick to getting the rosemary aroma to come through?

Comment: What's your source of rosemary?  Adding that to the question may help folks help you.

Comment: Is the rosemary dried or fresh?

Comment: What's the source of the recipe?

Comment: @FuzzyChef Why? Is very freshly picked rosemary essential? Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @Erica fresh rosemary

Comment: I suspect that you're burning it too much. It's just a guess (so not an answer), and I'd test it only I'm currently damaged and in no fit state for experiments

Comment: Phil: because I wasn't sure how fresh it was.  If it's dried out, I can see it burning before it gives off any scent.  I wasn't going to post that as an answer, though, because I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 4):

You need fresh rosemary and give it a quick *char* and not allow it to burn. That's sort of the same technique of using a blowtorch for crème brulée and the same "doneness" of charred vegetables - caramelized but not burnt

If you're smelling smoke, it is already too burnt to use.